# Subir imagen al servidor y renombrarla

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buen día, básicamente necesito tomar una imagen y re-nombrarla con el nombre que proporcione el usuario en un input y subirla al servidor.

Con este código ya sube las imágenes al servidor solo faltaría nombrarlas con el la clave que proporcione el usuario en el input, ya que si lo intento de la manera de abajo me marca el siguiente error:

```js
Notice: Undefined index: clave in C:\wamp64\www\Idis\php\upload.php on line 2
```

Código HTML:

```html
<form id="formUpl">
  <input id="fachada" name="clave"/>
  <span>Imagenes</span>
  <input type="file" name="archivo[]" multiple>
  <button type="submit">Subir</button>
</form>
```

Código JS

```js
$("#formUpl").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formulario = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "php/upload.php",
            data:formulario,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(respAX) {
                if (respAX == 0) {
                    alert("ERROR");
                } else {
                    console.log(respAX);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Y el código Php con el que quiero nombrar la foto y subirla al servidor.

```js
<?php
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$total = count($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'][$i];
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    $newname = $clave.'.jpg';
    print_r($clave); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath,"uploads/".$newname)) {
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu código php deberías agregar lo siguiente;

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $carpeta_destino . $nombre_archivo);
```

Ojo, en base a mi experiencia cree esta función para extraer la extensión del archivo y guardarlo con el nombre que to elija (o que en tu caso el usuario coloque);

```
//Este codigo va antes que todo

function extencion_archivo($nombre_archivo){
            $path = $nombre_archivo;
            $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            return $ext;
        }
```

Quedaría así;

```
<?php

$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$nombre_archivo=$clave.".".extencion_archivo($_FILES['archivo']['name']) ;
$total = count($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'][$i];
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $carpeta_destino . $nombre_archivo);
    print_r($clave); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath,"uploads/".$nombre_archivo)) {
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
  }
}
?>
```